# "It holds that"

Tags: sentence-usage

Usually we write the sentence "That Mary is a girl holds" as "It holds that Mary is a girl".

My question is: What if we have more than one thing to say? I.e. how to write the sentence "That Mary is a girl and that John is a boy hold" as the begin-with-it form?

Comment: As far as I understand, it would be the same, i.e. "It holds that Mary is a girl and that John is a boy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only heard *holds true*, not just *holds* by itself. (AmE)

In any case, your sentence should be:

> That Mary is a girl and John is a boy holds.

We need to know what "That" is, because that is the subject. It will be singular so use "holds".
For example:

> The claim that Mary is a girl and John is a boy holds.

Here the subject is "The claim", which is singular.

Then,

> It holds that Mary is a girl and John is a boy.

Here the subject is "it" (whatever it is) and singular so again use "holds".

Comment: Ah thanks so much. I see how to combine two things to be said so that the begin-with-it form is recovered. Thanks!

Comment: I have heard *holds* by itself (rather than *holds true*) a lot, especially in mathematics. (I am a native British English speaker).

Comment: @jfhc I edited my answer to indicate AmE. Or maybe its just me.